# Grails undirectional hasMany createCriteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

The ability to use **Pagination** is the goal, however I'm not sure how to work with this. The relationship is unidirectional hasMany (seen below). As current it works fine **without** pagination (see [Screenshot](http://d.pr/i/xCiQ)), but to work with pagination I have to change the controller to use createCriteria. This is where I come into difficulty as its quite strange for the relationship.

*Domain*

```
Class Tag {

      String Tag
      User user

      static hasMany = [events: Event]
}
```

*Controller*

```
def searchTags() {
    println("TAG CONTROLLER  -  Params sent on click of tag are:  "+params.selected)
    def results = Tag.findByTagAndUser(params.selected, lookupPerson())

    //resultTotal is for show for the time being 
    [query: params.selected, results: results, resultTotal: 0]
}
```

*GSP*

```
<g:each in="${results.events}" status="i" var="t">
   .... ommited as unnessary
</g:each>

//Not working yet due to confusing createCriteria issue
<div class="pagination">
    <g:paginate total="${resultTotal}" />
</div>
```

I could do with a little guidance, this is what I'm thinking so far but I'm a little confused:

```
    def tagCriteria = Tag.createCriteria()
    def result = tagCriteria.list (max: 50, offset: 10) {
        eq("tag", params.selected)
        and {
            eq("user", lookupPerson())
        }
        //Not sure what to do at this point compared with the findByTagAndUser(params.selected, lookupPerson()).events  events being the hasMany relationship seen in domain
        events {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
def searchTags() {        
    def tagCriteria = Tag.createCriteria()
    def results = tagCriteria.list (max: 50, offset: 10) {

        eq("tag", params.selected)
        eq("user", lookupPerson())            

        projections {
            property("events")
        }
    }

    [query: params.selected, results: results, resultTotal: results.totalCount]
}
```

HQL version - The problem is you have to do the same query twice, but select the `count(e)`

```
Tag.executeQuery("""
Select e
from Tag t join t.events as e
where t.tag = :selected
and t.user = :user
""", [selected: params.selected, user: lookupPerson()], [max: 50, offset 10])
```

Comment: Thanks James, but that doesn't work.

the `results` returned gives something quite weird according to IntelliJ A list object containing a set i.e. `List<Set<Events>>`

There will only ever be **one tag that matches** the way I've designed this, I don't know if that will help in any suggestions? I'm coming up blank with this one, doesn't seem like it's possible, but surely someone has had this issue :/

Comment: p.s. the totalCount does return one, which technically is right as there will only ever be one Tag object, but obviously there's many events linked to that one tag. Hope you can solve this :)

Comment: In order to paginate the events, you have to query the events. I would suggest using HQL

Comment: Please excuse me for the late reply, I will try this in an hour, see if I can sort it with your help thanks James as always :)

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by query twice here James, timid of HQL as I've not really had any experience with this as of yet... sorry for the late reply I've just been stupidly busy

Comment: If you want to get a total count of the results that you would have received had you not used pagination, you have to query twice.